# Dummy Masking in Password Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, passwords

Is there any way by which i can able to mask the password. Currently i am having two jsp pages, first is list.jsp which will list all the user related records and and on clicking to one user it will redirect to next page i.e. details.jsp which will fetch the user details records from database(username,password and desc).

In database password is stored in encrypted format. While fetching the userDetails password value will come in encrypted format, but i am not concern about decrypting.

Now, password field will be shown as blank, i wanted to mask this password field instead of showing empty.

```
jQuery.getJSON(
    restURL ,function(data) {
       jQuery.each(data, function(field, value) {
         if(field == "userName"){
            $("#userName").val(value);
         }
          if(field == "password"){
            // password value in ecrypted format 7a95dec218ffaaf8992bb48b4bd94367
             var dummy = "";
             for(i=0;i<value.length;i++){
                 dummy += "*";
             }
             $("#password").val(dummy);
          }
          if(field == "descrption"){
            $("#desc").val(value);
          }     
      });                               
    });



           <tr>
                <td>UserName:</td>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;" width=1><input type="text" id="userName" name="" size=48 value=""></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px;" width=1><input type="password" name="" id="password" size=48 value=""/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Description</td>
              <td style="padding-right: 10px;" width=1><input type="text" id="desc" name="" size=48 value=""></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
```

whenever i am getting response from server, i am just trying to replace password with dummy string i.e "*", but some how the password field is still blank.Can some body point out what exactly i am doing wrong and how to solve this problem[image][image]

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are you sure the property in the JSON object is called `password`? Why are you using a loop, anyway? Why not just `$("#userName").val(data.userName)`?

Comment: @Barmar--attached another snapshot which i captured from firebug ...the field is password only

Comment: Aren't encrypted passwords always the same length? Why not just put `$("#password").val("********************************");`?

Comment: @Barmar-- yes the encrypted password length is always same. I also tried  earlier the same way which u mentioned now, but still password field is blank.

Comment: Your code works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mfqggt7y/2/

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your reply,just saw in fiddle its working..but unfortunately it's not working in my browser with the same code.